# jQuery timer not working on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, timer

I am trying to fire an event 3 seconds after the user has stopped typing to check the input to see if it meets the minimum length requirement. If it does, then show as valid and if less than 14 characters show as invalid/error. I want onkeydown to clear timer, check for positive validation, and if it fails to start another timer.

```
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 3000;  //time in ms, 3 second for example

// on keydown, start the countdown
$('#contact_phone').keydown(function(){
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
if ($('#contact_phone').val().length == 14) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
}
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
$('#contact_phone').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 14) {
        $(this).removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Is it working for you? what problems are you having (if any?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the **keyup event** every single time the timer expires.

**You need not bind both the events to the input**. '
Remove the keydown and replace it with keyup event.

```
var typingTimer; //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 3000; //time in ms, 5 second for example

// on keydown, start the countdown
$('#contact_phone').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping() {
    var $this = $('#contact_phone');

    if ($this.val().length == 14) {
        $this.removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BSrd/)**

Comment: @user2736472.. Removed the 2nd event that is not required. Also changed the event name from `onkeyup` to `keyup`

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are waiting until after user stops typing to bind the `keyup` event. Since user has stopped typing...this event will never fire.

Try:

```
// on keydown, start the countdown
$('#contact_phone').keydown(function () {
    var $input= $(this);
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#contact_phone').val().length == 14) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            doneTyping($input);
        }, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping($input) {

        if ($input.val().length == 14) {
            $input.removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        } else {
           $input.removeClass('whiteBorder').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        }

}
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net